# Trigger to detect user password change

Tags: trigger

When a user change the password, the API field, LastPasswordChangeDate, on the User got updated. This can be seen with SOQL query. However, the UserTrigger never fires. The UserTrigger fires properly when other normal user fields got changed. How do I detect this user password change event? If using a trigger, then, on which table? Are there any other ways?

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353854/apex-trigger-to-detect-password-reset-change; also SetupAuditTrail tracks this and that object is queryable

Answer (score 2):

There are some [Operations That Don't Invoke Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm). Even though this page doesn't call out password changes specifically, it makes sense that triggers would not fire, because triggers generally only fire if there is an actual DML operation (insert, update, upsert, merge, delete, or undelete). Setting or resetting a user's password doesn't fall into any of these six categories, as the API call is setPassword or resetPassword, rather than any of those six DML operations.